# How to convert from vector to const array

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constants

I have an API for the functions, say:

```
void func (const char** s,const size_t* ss);
```

I.e. the function gets the const array of null terminated strings [`s`] and their sizes [`ss`].
I get the strings during run-time and not aware about their amount.
What I thought to do is to define `vector<char*> vS` - insert the strings to it and define `vector<size_t> vSS` - insert the strings sizes to it.
Eventually I should transfer `vector<char*> vS` to `const char**`
and `vector<size_t> vSS` to `const size_t*`.
I am aware that exists a trick `&vS[0]` / `&vSS[0]`.The problem is that the above generates `char**` and `size_t* ss` respectively.**But** I am missing **const**.
How the issue could be solved?

Comment: How an API knows how many strings are in `s` and how many sizes are in `ss` ?

Comment: it gets additional param count,which says that.It was not important the the question theme ==> didn`t add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing params to function (and not trying to pass results back in the arguments), than non-const'ness is not a problem: you may use `char *` anywhere where `cont char *` is required.

But you have problems with double pointers - `const char **`, etc. They are not converted implicitly because it can lead to const violation. You can read an explanation in [C++ FAQ Light](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/constptrptr-conversion.html).

In your case you can just create a `vector<const char*>`, as @aschepler said.

BTW, `const char**` is not "const pointer to pointer to char", but "pointer to const pointer to char", you have to add another `const` if you want to ensure that function doesn't change the outer pointer contents. `const char * const *` or `char const * const *`, which is the same - pointer to const pointer to const characters.

(BTW, reading right-to-left relly helps when dealing with multiple consts: try it with the last expression from the previous paragraph. And yes, you can add another `const` at the end of this exprssion to get "const pointer to const pointer to const char").

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to fix the API to make it const-correct, then change it to:

```
void func (const char* const* s,const size_t* ss);
```

Otherwise, if you don't need to modify the string contents via the vector, then change the vector to:

```
vector<const char*> vS;
```

Otherwise, you'll need to do a `const_cast` and trust the API not to modify anything:

```
func(const_cast<const char**>(&vS[0]), &vSS[0]);
```

(If you're interested, the problem with passing `char**` to a function taking `const char**` is that the function could modify one of the pointers to point to a `const char`. The caller would then have a non-const pointer to that `const` object, with nothing to prevent him trying to modify it. Boom! Undefined behaviour.)

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `vS` as

```
vector<const char*> vS;
```

Then `&vS[0]` is `const char**`.  And `size_t*` can implicitly convert to `const size_t*`.

(By the way, `func` probably should be

```
void func(const char* const* s, const size_t* ss);
```

but the above will work either way.)

Comment: isnt that double const redundant? (in the const char* const* s)

Comment: @Rookie: No: the first prevents modification of the string contents, the second prevents modification of the pointers to the strings.